# Is training data required for collaborative filtering methods?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I'm about to start writing a recommender system for videos, mostly based on collaborative filtering as video metadata is pretty sparse, with a bit of content-based filtering as well. However, I'm not sure what to do about training data. Is training data something of importance in recommender systems, specifically in collaborative methods? If so, how can I generate that kind of data, or what type of data should I look for?

Comment: Do you need data to train a model on? of course. Are you asking whether you need any user-item interaction data, in addition to other metadata you already have for sure? I don't think you can generate the real-world data you mean to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Any ML algorithm needs data. Take [Matrix Factorization](http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/) approach, for example.

It receives (incomplete) matrix of rates: rows represent users, columns represent items and a cell contains rate that particular user rated particular item. Then by factorizing this matrix you obtain latent vector representation for each user and each item, thus allowing you to predict future rates. Obviously, unseen items with highest rate are most interesting to the user, *according to the model*.

Essentially, Matrix Factorization learns predicting new rates for known users and items.